# May I call Bundle#putString method in API level 19?

Tags: android

[In documentation for API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) level 19, there is no putString method in Bundle class.
But I can call Bundle#putString method and my app works fine.

May I call putString method ?
Why do my app work fine ?

Environment:

- Write code by Kotlin
- Android Studio 2.1.1
- compileSdkVersion 24
- buildToolsVersion 24.0.1
- nminSdkVersion 17
- targetSdkVersion 24

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin apply() extension lint message in Android Studio 3.0-alpha8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415947/kotlin-apply-extension-lint-message-in-android-studio-3-0-alpha8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because the `Bundle` extends `BaseBundle` which has `putString()`. So, yes you can use it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know what you tell me but BaseBundle is requires API level 21 or higher. I mentioned on API level 19.

Comment: Hey, its ok. Thats what this community is all about :).

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. Please tell me detail.

Comment: Alright, if you look at the source code of bundle for api 19 here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/os/Bundle.java#Bundle you can see `getString()` exists. So, they must have moved it to `BaseBundle` at API 19, I guess. Over at documentation, they are showing a class in its current form (i.e. with latest implementation).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you can use `putString`. Another option is to use `putCharSequence` (`String` is a `CharSequence`)

Comment: Thank you. I know `putCharacterSequence`. Why you **suppose** that ? Is there the documentation ?