# Kotlin apply() extension lint message in Android Studio 3.0-alpha8

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

I have following code that produces following lint error.
[image: lint issue]

```
fun newInstance(message: String?): DialogFragment {
    return DialogFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("arg", message)
        }
    }
}
```

The message points out that `this` reference inside `apply()` function points to `BaseBundle` class that is available since API 21 which will crash on lower API. [Bundle#putString(key, value)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ics-mr1/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java#483) is definitely available on lower versions, but there is an error in Android Studio 3.0-alpha8.

The issue quite strange as I can see decompiled code as this:
[image: decompiled]

Which do reference `Bundle` type not a `BaseBundle`.

Why do we have Lint error in first place?

Comment: how did you decompile the code?

Comment: @lelloman I did relied on Android Studio "Show Kotlin Bytecode". There is a "Decompile" button in the tab that appears on right side of Android Studio pane. Another way is to use "classyshark-bytecode-viewer", but I have not tried it.

Comment: cool thx! I tried your code and I noticed one thing, if I make TestKt class extends View, the warning disappear.. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use `let` instead of `apply`, like:

```
fun newInstance(message: String?): DialogFragment {
    return DialogFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().let {
            it.putString("arg", message)
            it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>It really looks like a bug</s> It is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12015) but one could actually see why you're getting the warning if looking at Bundle.java source code.

Before api 21 `Bundle` had a method ([check here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/os/Bundle.java?av=f#Bundle.putString%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29))

```
public void putString(@Nullable String key, @Nullable String value)
```

and the class itself had no super class. From api 21 `Bundle` extends a newly added `BaseBundle` class and this method `putString` had been [moved](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/os/BaseBundle.java?av=f#BaseBundle.getString%28java.lang.String%29) to `BaseBundle`. So, when you call the method on api 21 and above, the method belongs to `BaseBundle`, for lower version it belongs to `Bundle`.

This is somehow related to the `apply` block because the warning doesn't appear if you call the method on a `Bundle`-type variable directly.